# memory management using malloc while running

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

Below is my C program:

```
int main(int argc, const char *const *argv) {

  char **upArgs = manipulate(argc, argv, toupper);
  char **lowArgs = manipulate(argc, argv, tolower);

  for (char *const *p = upArgs, *const *q = lowArgs; *p && *q; ++argv, ++p, ++q) {
    printf("[%s] -> [%s] [%s]\n", *argv, *p, *q);
  }
  free_args(upArgs, lowArgs, NULL);
}


char **manipulate(int argc, const char *const *argv, int (*const change)(int)){
    
    char **retArr = malloc((argc+1) * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {

        const char *const str = argv[i];
        size_t len = strlen(str);

        char* modified = malloc((len+1) * sizeof(char));

        for (size_t j = 0; j < (len+1); ++j) {
            modified[j] = change(str[j]);
        }
        retArr[i] = modified;
   } 
   return retArr;
}


 void free_args(char **args, ...){
    va_list arg;
    
    va_start(arg, args);
    for(int i =0;i < **args; i++){
        char *ar = va_arg(arg, char*);
        free(ar);
    }
    
    va_end(arg);
}
```

When I run "leaks -atExit -- ./test" there are no memory leaks.
But when I run "./test" i get the below error.

**malloc: *** error for object 0x7f95324059c8: pointer being freed was not allocated**

Where am I going wrong here in my memory allocation?

Comment: That's not how variadic functions work. Try putting a `printf("%d\n", i);` in the `for` loop, and watch the fireworks.

Comment: Why do you think `**args` will contain the number of arguments to free? You never stored `argc` there.

Comment: Why does the title say "while compiling"? The error is coming when you run the program, not when you compile it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**args` is not the number of arguments that were passed to `free_args`. You're using a `NULL` sentinel to indicate the end of the arguments, so you should check for that.

Also, the types of the arguments are `char**`, not `char*`.

When looping over the arguments, you need to start with `args`, then use `va_arg` to get the additional arguments.

```
void free_args(char **args, ...){
    va_list arg;
    
    va_start(arg, args);
    for (char **ar = args; ar != NULL; ar = va_arg(arg, char**)) {
        free(ar);
    }   
    va_end(arg);
}
```

Note that this *does* have a memory leak. You're freeing the `upArgs` and `lowArgs` arrays, but not freeing all the strings that they point to. I'm not showing how to fix that, I assume it was intention so that `leak` would report the problem.

When I use

```
leaks --atExit -- ./testleaks a Bcd EF
```

I get the following leak report:

```
Process 30435: 8 leaks for 128 total leaked bytes.

    8 (128 bytes) << TOTAL >>
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f606880 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f606890 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f6068a0 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f6068b0 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f6068f0 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f606900 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f606910 [16]
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x13f606920 [16]
```

Comment: But when i run "leaks" it shows 0 memory leaks.

Comment: @Redman What is "leaks"?  Use valgrind instead.

Comment: @Redman I get 8 memory leaks, which is as expected.

Comment: @Barmar oh yes i used your command and i got 9 leaks. Is it because i did not free "modified" and "retArray" in my manipulate function? and i did not free *p and *q too?

Comment: You can't free them in `manipulate`, because you want to return them to the caller. You need to free them in `free_args`.

Comment: By calling free_args in my manipulate function and passing "modified" and "retArray" as parameters?